# Tkinter is opening a second windows when the first one is closing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a budget manager and I have added a textBox in the main window.

However, there seems to be a bug: When I close the window while running the script for the first time since I started my IDE, the window opens, then restarts when I close it, but I can't figure it out.

Here are all the programs:

**Main**

```
from moneyTable import moneyTable
from textBoxManager import textBox
import tkinter as tk
import fileLoader as fl
import miscAdditions as ma
import categoryAddOrRemove as caor



filesLoaded = fl.loadFile('/home/thanatos_0173/Desktop')
isFileNotEmpty = filesLoaded[0]
moneyClass = filesLoaded[1]
moneyQuantity = filesLoaded[2]


mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.resizable(True, True)
mainWindow.title("budgetGestionnary.th")
mainWindow.attributes('-zoomed',True)
mainWindow.config(background=(ma.rgb_to_hex(100, 100, 100)))



moneyTable(mainWindow,moneyClass,moneyQuantity,350,350,isFileNotEmpty)

textBox = tk.Text(mainWindow,height=10,width = 228)

textBox.place(x=10,y=830)
textBox.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
sb = tk.Scrollbar(tk.Frame(mainWindow))
sb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)
textBox.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
sb.config(command=textBox.yview)

def removeCategory():
     window = tk.Toplevel()
     window.minsize(200,200)
     window.resizable(False,False)
     clicked = tk.StringVar()
     clicked.set(moneyClass[0])
     dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(window, clicked, *moneyClass)
     dropdown.place(x=10,y=10)

     def remove():
         window.destroy()
         elementRemoved = caor.removeElement(moneyClass,moneyQuantity,clicked.get(),moneyQuantity[moneyClass.index(clicked.get())])
         moneyTable(mainWindow,elementRemoved[0],elementRemoved[1],350,350,isFileNotEmpty)
         if len(moneyClass) == 0:
              remove_category_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
     button = tk.Button(window,text = "Delete category", command = remove)
     button.place(x=10,y=50)

def addCategory():
     window = tk.Toplevel()
     window.minsize(200,200)
     window.resizable(False,False)
     clicked = tk.StringVar()
     clicked.set('Category Name')
     nameEntry = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=clicked)
     nameEntry.place(x=10,y=10)
     clicked2 = tk.StringVar()
     clicked2.set('Category Default Money')
     moneyEntry = tk.Entry(window,textvariable=clicked2)
     moneyEntry.place(x=10,y=40)
     def add():
          window.destroy()
          elementAdded = caor.addElement(moneyClass,moneyQuantity,clicked.get(),clicked2.get())
          moneyTable(mainWindow,elementAdded[0],elementAdded[1],350,350,isFileNotEmpty)
          remove_category_button.config(state='normal')
     button = tk.Button(window,text = "Add category", command = add)
     button.place(x=10,y=150)

def addMessageMain(message):
     textBox.config(state = tk.NORMAL)
     textBox.insert('end',message+"\n")
     textBox.config(state = tk.DISABLED)

remove_category_button = tk.Button(mainWindow,text="Remove a category",command = removeCategory)

add_category_button = tk.Button(mainWindow,text="Add a category",command = addCategory)

remove_category_button.place(x=30, y=785, height=33)
add_category_button.place(x=190, y=785, height=33)

if not isFileNotEmpty:
     remove_category_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

**moneyTable.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import miscAdditions as ma


def moneyTable(window,categoryList:list,quantityList:list,sizeX:int,sizeY:int,isEmpty:bool,*arg:str):
    if len(categoryList) != len(quantityList):
        raise ValueError("The list:",categoryList,"haven't the same length than the list:",quantityList)
    elementList = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(categoryList)):
        tempList = []
        tempList.append(categoryList[i])
        tempList.append(str(quantityList[i])+" €")
        total += quantityList[i]
        elementList.append(tempList)
    elementList.append(["TOTAL", str(total) + " €"])
    frame = tk.LabelFrame(window)
    frame.grid(padx=30, pady=30,ipadx=sizeX, ipady=sizeY, row=0)
    frame.config(background=(ma.rgb_to_hex(100, 100, 100)),bd=3)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)
    column_list = ["Category", "Money"]
    tree['columns'] = column_list
    tree["show"] = "headings"
    for column in column_list:
        tree.heading(column, text=column)
        max = 0
        for i in range(len(categoryList)):
            if len(categoryList[i]) > max:
                max = len(categoryList[i])
        if column == column_list[0]:
            tree.column(column, width=max*8)
        else:
            tree.column(column, width=50)
    tree.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
    treescrollY = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
    treescrollY.configure(command=tree.yview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=treescrollY.set)
    treescrollY.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    treescrollX = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
    treescrollX.configure(command=tree.xview)
    tree.configure(xscrollcommand=treescrollX.set)
    treescrollX.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
    def handle_click(event):
        if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "separator":
            return "break"
    tree.bind('<Button-1>', handle_click)
    if not isEmpty or arg[0] == "--devmode":
        ma.reloadTreeview(tree, elementList)
    return tree
```

**textBoxManager.py**

```
import tkinter as tk


def textBox(window,x,y,height,width):
    textBox = tk.Text(
        window,
        height=height,
        width = width,
        wrap = 'word'
    )

    textBox.place(x=x,y=y)
    textBox.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(tk.Frame(window))
    sb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)
    textBox.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    sb.config(command=textBox.yview)

    return textBox
```

**fileLoader.py**

```
import miscAdditions as ma
import customFileSaver as cfs
#Create the arrays outside of the function to access it from other class
__spec__ = 'test'

def loadFile(defaultPath:str):
    moneyComingCategory = []
    moneyAvailableComingCategory = []
    cfs.loadOrCreateDirectory(defaultPath,".budgetGestionnary")
    defaultPath += "/.budgetGestionnary"
    cfs.loadOrCreateFile(defaultPath,".savedata.txt")
    with open(".savedata.txt") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    cfs.loadOrCreateDirectory(defaultPath,".removedMoney")
    defaultPath += "/.removedMoney"
    cfs.loadOrCreateFile(defaultPath, ".removedMoney.txt")
    with open('.removedMoney.txt') as f:
        lines2 = f.readlines()
    removedMoneyList = []
    for i in lines2:
        removedMoneyList.append(ma.str_to_list(i))
    if lines != []:
        moneyComingCategory = ma.str_to_list(lines[0])
        moneyAvailableComingCategory = [eval(i) for i in ma.str_to_list(lines[1])]
        isFileNotEmpty = True
    else:
        isFileNotEmpty = False
    return [isFileNotEmpty,moneyComingCategory,moneyAvailableComingCategory]
```

**miscAdditions.py**

```
import tkinter as tk


def rgb_to_hex(r, g, b):
    return("#"+"0"*(2-len(hex(r)[2:]))+hex(r)[2:]+"0"*(2-len(hex(g)[2:]))+hex(g)[2:]+"0"*(2-len(hex(b)[2:]))
    + hex(b)[2:])


def str_to_list(arg):
    arg = arg.split()
    return arg


def list_to_string(arg):
    strl1 = ""
    for ele in arg:
        strl1 += str(ele) + " "
    return strl1


def reloadTreeview(tree, list):
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    for row in list:
        tree.insert("", "end", values=row)


def convertActualMoneyList(list, char, list1, list2):
    list.clear()
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        tempList = []
        tempList.append(list1[i])
        tempList.append(str(list2[i])+" "+char)
        total += list2[i]
        list.append(tempList)
    list.append(["TOTAL", str(total) + " €"])
    return list


def disableAndEnabledDropdownWhenListContainOneElement(list, element, dropdown):
    if len(list) == 1 and list == [element]:
        dropdown.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    else:
        dropdown.config(state="normal")


def dropdownReloader(screen,StringVar,list,dropdown,x,y):
    StringVar = tk.StringVar()
    StringVar.set(list[0])
    dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(screen, StringVar,*list)
    dropdown.place(x=x,y=y)

def listTransformer(list:list):
        for k in list:
            tempList = []
            for i in range(len(list)):
                if i <= 2:
                    tempList.append(k[i])
                elif i == 3:
                    tempList.append(str(k[i]+" €"))
                else:
                    tempVariable = ""
                    for v in range(4, len(k)):
                        tempVariable += k[v] + " "
                        tempList.append(tempVariable)
            list[list.index(k)] = tempList
            return list

space = "                                                                                                                                                                                                              "
```

**customFileSaver.py**

```
import os
import miscAdditions as ma


def loadOrCreateDirectory(path, dirToCheckOrCreate):
    os.chdir(path)
    customDir = path +"/"+ dirToCheckOrCreate
    if not os.path.exists(customDir):
        os.system("mkdir " + dirToCheckOrCreate)


def loadOrCreateFile(path,fileToCheckOrCreate):
    os.chdir(path)
    customdir = path + "/" + fileToCheckOrCreate
    if not os.path.exists(customdir):
        os.system("touch " + fileToCheckOrCreate)


def saveRemovedMoney(list,path,fileToOpen):
    os.chdir(path)
    with open(fileToOpen,"a") as file:
        file.write(ma.list_to_string(list)+os.linesep)


def saveActualMoney(list1,list2,path,fileToOpen):
    os.chdir(path)
    file = open(fileToOpen,"a")
    l1 = ma.list_to_string(list1)
    l2 = ma.list_to_string(list2)
    file.writelines([l1+os.linesep, l2+os.linesep])
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]? Right now, there is too much code for us to read through. Try removing code while the bug persists until you have a minimal example that we can copy/paste/edit.

Comment: I've already tried, but I try it again and tell you what append.

Comment: Okay. Very strange. When I run the script, with the same window, but without all the widgets (for example, the textBox), it opens first the window with all the widgets, and then the "new window", with less widgets. I don't know if I am very clear, I am French and my English is probably bad. I think the error comes from python, I'll try to change the directory to see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, bad hypothesis. Forget what I said.

Comment: Ok. So, the error is happening when I'm importing this:
`from moneyTable import moneyTable

from textBoxManager import textBox

import tkinter as tk

import fileLoader as fl

import miscAdditions as ma

import categoryAddOrRemove as caor`

The file doesn't need anything else to screw up.

Comment: Found ! The error is happening when I'm inporting `categoryAddOrRemove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So, the error is that I imported main (testeeeeee.py) into categoryAddOrRemove. The window initialization was not in a function, so it was initializing the window at once.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as the accepted answer. This helps in maintaining the quality of Stackoverflow!